# Regular Expression to extract part of string

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a string in the form of

```
Foo
"Foo"
"Some Foo"
"Some Foo and more"
```

I need to extract the value `Foo` which is in quotes and can be surrounded by any number of alphanumeric and white space characters.  So, for the examples above I would like the output to be

```
<NoMatch>
Foo
Foo
Foo
```

I have been trying to get this to work, and this is the pattern I have so far using lookahead/lookbehind for quotes.  This works for `"Foo"` but not others.

```
(?<=")Foo(?=")
```

Further expanding this to

```
(?<=")(?<=.*?)Foo(?=.*?)(?=")
```

does not work.

Any assistance will be appreciated!

Comment: You said "surrounded by alphanumeric characters". Quotes and whitespace aren't alphanumeric.

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: I am using this as part of a search and replace, in notepad++

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, I have reworded the question

Comment: Can you be sure that a) quotes are always correctly balanced? b) there aren't any escaped quotes? c) quoted strings never span multiple lines?

Comment: @TimPietzcker yes they will always be balanced and no other quotes are expected in the text.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If quotes are correctly balanced and quoted strings don't span multiple lines, then you can simply look ahead in the string to check whether an even number of quotes follows. If that's not true, we know that we're inside a quoted string:

```
Foo(?![^"\r\n]*(?:"[^"\r\n]*"[^"\r\n]*)*$)
```

**Explanation:**

```
Foo          # Match Foo
(?!          # only if the following can't be matched here:
 [^"\r\n]*   # Any number of characters except quotes or newlines
 (?:         # followed by
  "[^"\r\n]* # (a quote and any number of non-quotes/newlines
  "[^"\r\n]* # twice)
 )*          # any number of times.
 $           # End of the line
)            # End of lookahead assertion
```

See it live on [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/xP1qS1)

Comment: Is there a way to exclude the line if there are no quotes? Currently this pattern matches `Foo` as well as `"Foo"`.

Comment: @Kami: No, it shouldn't do that. See the test link. It may be that you need to prepend `(?m)` to the regex to make sure that `$` matches at the end of a line, not just at the end of the file. But usually that is the default behaviour in text editors.

Answer (score 3):

Look-around (`(?<=something)` and `(?=something)`) don't work on variable-lenght patterns, i.e., on `.*`. Try this:

```
(?<=")(.*?)(Foo)(.*?)(?=")
```

and then use match strings (depending on your language: `$1,$2,...` or `\1,\2,...` or members of some array or something like that).

Comment: This matches the entire line, I would like to only extract `Foo`

Comment: @Kami You are extracting it as the second match string. Admittedly, look-arounds are of no use here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something with this kind of pattern:

```
"[^"]*?Foo[^"]*?"
```

Comment: This matches the entire line, I would like to only extract `Foo`

Comment: @Kami: you must add capturing parenthesis around what you want to preserve

Answer (score 0):

In Notepad++

```
search : ("[^"]*)Foo([^"]*")
replace : $1Bar$2
```

Comment: What if there are two `Foo`s inside a quoted string?

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Only one is replaced. But it's may be enough as OP doesn't say anything about it.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: you push the replaceAll button a second time

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Yuk. :)