# Regex to extract date time from given string

Tags: c#, regex

I want to extract date from the string through regex.

String : log-bb-2014-02-12-12-06-13-diag

How to do it?

Comment: How about just split your string with `-` and concatenate items which they contains only numbers?

Comment: hav to do only through regex....

Comment: How does you regex look so far?

Comment: have tried looking this link but not getting

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16733230/regular-expression-to-extract-part-of-string

Comment: Judging by your requirement for it to be only a regex, I suspect this is a homework question - is that right? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions?lq=1

Comment: http://regexone.com/ is a good start

Comment: @JoaoRaposo any other website to learn regex at a more advanced level than regexone ?

Comment: @ManishTiwari what should be the date in the string you have mentioned ? is it 12th feb 2014 or 12th june 2013 ?

Comment: @aelor have a look at http://www.rexegg.com

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here something to start:

```
string s = "log-bb-2014-02-12-12-06-13-diag";
Regex r = new Regex(@"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}");
Match m = r.Match(s);
if(m.Success)
{
    DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(m.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Comment: `@"\d{4}(-\d\d){5}"`

Comment: `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`

Comment: The using statement is `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`

Answer (score 11):

Try this

```
(\d+)[-.\/](\d+)[-.\/](\d+)
```

## [Regex Demo](http://rubular.com/r/kcqDdLJBpx).

It will match all date formats

Answer (score 3):

Considering your date to be just `2014-02-12` i.e. 12th feb 2014.I hev written the below code to extract that part using ruby

```
str = 'log-bb-2014-02-12-12-06-13-diag'

str.scan(/\d{4}.\d{2}.\d{2}/)
```

will return `["2014-02-12"]`

regex is written within two `/`

`\d` means any integer, 
`{}` curly braces with any integer means number of times it has been repeated, `.` means any character. Here I have used it for `-`

Answer (score 0):

I have checked all above suggestions but none worked for if date format is "November 11, 2000". As this was a constant format that I need to extract for my problem here is the solution for it.

> [A-Z]\w*\s\d*\W*\d{4}

**Note:** This regex is specifically to extract date in the above mentioned format, if the order is randomized for eg. "11 November, 2000". This Regex won't give suitable result.
However slight modification in the above re, would give proper results.