# How to use IndexOf to get two separate parts in a string

Tags: c#, indexing

I have some code where I receive results (start up times) and want to paste these results along with in a txt file.

I have tried using the below code but at the moment that just gets the index of Start up time and the rest of the line which works but I cant seem to get the date aswell.

```
using (var process = Process.Start(psi))
{
    results = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: I would start by doing a `String.Split` on your `results`, using a space character as the delimiter.  This will give you an array containing all of the "words" in the `results`.

Comment: I'd suggest using RegEx to extract the timestamps from the entire string. That will make it a lot easier and less brittle. See this post and similar for some examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21723697/regex-to-extract-date-time-from-given-string

Comment: @blakeh This question changed significantly. An edit was made to remove test and expected data. Was that on purpose?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use Regex:

```
string date = null, startup_time = null;
var match = Regex.Match(results, @"(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2})");
if(match.Success)
{
     date = match.Groups[1].Value;
}
match = Regex.Match(results, @"(scene startup time:\s*(\d+ms)");
if(match.Success)
{
     startup_time = match.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

If you want to do it with `IndexOf()`:

```
    string search = "Total scene startup time:";
    int start = results.IndexOf(search) + search.Length;
    string startup = results.Substring(start, results.IndexOf("ms", start + 1) + 2 - start).Trim();
    Console.WriteLine(startup);
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qqpkNI)